# Using cursor in ArcPy gives TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Polygon' objects?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, typeerror

I have been trying to use arcpy.da.seachcursor to rip through a datasets rows and use each in an intersect analysis like so:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_feature, ['SHAPE@', 'NAME']) as cursor:
    for f in cursor:
        data = []
        print '...Working on {}'.format(f[1])
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(in_folder):
            for i,x in enumerate(files):
                if x.endswith('.shp'):
                   arcpy.Intersect_analysis(os.path.join(path, x)+';' + f[0], 'in_memory\\r{}'.format(i))
                   data.append('in_memory\\r{}'.format(i))
        arcpy.Merge_management(data, out_folder + '\\out_dataset_{}.shp'.format(name))
        arcpy.Delete_management('in_memory\\')
```

it yields the following error code message:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Polygon' objects
```

Upon reviewing how to fix this, I have stumbled upon code like:

```
row[0].overlaps(row2[0])
```

that is used by da cursors (reference: https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/find-overlapping-features/). This has piqued my interest but I cannot find documentation on the implementation of this data structure. Where do I find it? Are there methods for doing other spatial processes like intersect?

Hopefully through this I find out the answer to my error code, but if anyone has a quick bit of knowledge outside of the data structure I am looking for info on, please drop it :)

Comment: arcpy.Intersect_analysis([os.path.join(path, name), f[0]], 'in_memory\\r{}'.format(i)) - RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intersect wants a list of inputs so this wont work: `arcpy.Intersect_analysis(os.path.join(path, name)+';' + f[0],...`

Also try copying the polygon object to the in memory workspace and use this as input to the intersection:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(f[0], r'in_memory\temp')
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([os.path.join(path, name), r'in_memory\temp'],..
```

For this to work you probably need to set

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```